# How to make nested Panel and Sizer work in wxpython

Tags: python, wxpython

I am learning wxpython and trying to get a nested panel to work. This is an exercise to prepare for a more complex screen, hence it may look a bit complicated, but that is with a purpose ;).
What I want to do is the following:
Create a top frame
Add a panel to it
add some text and an input field to it
Use a vertical boxsizer to do the panel lay out
Here is how I implemented it:

```
import wx
class MainWindow(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        #add position panel
        posPnl = wx.Panel(self)
        lbl1 = wx.StaticText(posPnl, label="Position")
        lbl2 = wx.StaticText(posPnl, label="Size")
        sizeCtrl = wx.TextCtrl(posPnl)

        posPnlSzr = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        posPnlSzr.Add(lbl1, 1, wx.GROW)
        posPnlSzr.Add(sizeCtrl, 1, wx.GROW)
        posPnlSzr.Add(lbl2, 1, wx.GROW)   

        #create a top leverl sizer to add to the frame itself
        mainSzr = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        mainSzr.Add(posPnlSzr)

        self.SetSizerAndFit(mainSzr)
        self.Show()


app = wx.App(False)
frame = MainWindow(None, "Trading Client")
app.MainLoop()
```

All i get is a small blank screen with the word 'Pos' on it. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The logic here is to create a `Panel` to add controls inside, then a `BoxSizer` where you declare how each control you add in the `Panel` behaves with resizing, and eventually to set on the `Panel` what is the `BoxSizer` applied on it.

You have 2 issues.

- First you are missing the last part of the above statement for the `posPnl`object. Add this:

  ```
  posPnl.SetSizer(posPnlSzr)
  ```

  once you have added the controls to `posPnlSzr`
- The second issue is that you are adding `posSnlSzr` in your `mainSzr`. It is wrong to do so. Again the logic is to add controls to a sizer, and you can view a `Panel` as a compounded control. Thus the correct code is to add `posPnl` into the `mainSzr`:

  ```
  mainSzr.Add(posPnl)
  ```

  As far I as read, you are trying to get `posPnl` automatically resized with the main window. If to add the panel so that `mainSzr` will actually resize it:

  ```
  mainSzr.Add(posPnl, 1, wx.GROW)
  ```

---

This gives the final source code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import wx
class MainWindow(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        #add position panel
        posPnl = wx.Panel(self)
        lbl1 = wx.StaticText(posPnl, label="Position")
        lbl2 = wx.StaticText(posPnl, label="Size")
        sizeCtrl = wx.TextCtrl(posPnl)

        posPnlSzr = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        posPnlSzr.Add(lbl1, 1, wx.GROW)
        posPnlSzr.Add(sizeCtrl, 1, wx.GROW)
        posPnlSzr.Add(lbl2, 1, wx.GROW)

        posPnl.SetSizer(posPnlSzr)

        #create a top leverl sizer to add to the frame itself
        mainSzr = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        mainSzr.Add(posPnl, 1, wx.GROW)

        self.SetSizerAndFit(mainSzr)
        self.Show()


app = wx.App(False)
frame = MainWindow(None, "Trading Client")
app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: Thanks, this is really helpful and clear. One question though: are you really of the opinion that you should never add a sizer to a sizer? I see this a lot also in fairly well known tutorials.

Comment: @Django: I don't think Boud says you should never add a sizer to a sizer, just that IN THIS CASE you are trying to add your StaticTexts and TextCtrls to the Panel but instead you're adding it to the Frame. The Frame contains mainSizer which contains posPnlSzr. posPnl DOES NOT contain posPnlSzr nor does the Frame contain posPnl. The problem is posPnl never really gets used. Boud's code fixes this.

Answer (score 0):

The basic form of my applications goes something like this (parent --> child):

frame --> panel --> sizer --> widgets/sizers

For certain things, I do this:

frame --> sizer --> panel --> sizer --> widgets/sizers

I nest sizers are the time. You usually want to sketch out your GUI on paper when you're a new programmer and then draw boxes around them to try to figure out which sizers work, where you'll want to nest them, etc.

You could fix this problem just by changing **self.SetSizerAndFit(mainSzr)** to **posPnl.SetSizerAndFit(mainSzr)**